# Finding solution for larger intervals with shooting method

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear, boundary-conditions, singularity

I am trying to solve numerically the following non linear differential equation:

$ y''(x)+\frac{3}{x}y'(x)=\frac{{\rm d}V(y)}{{\rm d}y},\qquad V(y)=\frac{1}{4}(y(x)^2-1)^2+\frac{a}{2}(y(x)-1),$

with boundary conditions:

$ y(\infty)= y_+,$  $\qquad$ $y'(0)=0,$

where $y_+$ is the local minima of the potential $V(y).$

I am using the following code:

```
    a = 0.23;
    V[y_] := (1/4 )(y^2 - 1)^2 + a (y - 1)/(2);
    ode = y''[x] + (3 y'[x])/x == V'[y[x]];
    extrema = Block[{y}, y /. NSolve[D[V[y], y] == 0, y, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 50]]

    xs = 10^-8; xm = 18;
    s = ParametricNDSolve[{ode, y'[xs] == 0, y[xm] ==extrema[[3]]}, y, {x, xs, xm}, {ys}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[xs] == ys, y'[xs] == 0}}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision,  AccuracyGoal -> 13, PrecisionGoal -> 13];
  
   f = y[extrema[[1]] + 0.000001] /. s; (*choosing the optimal value of ys to get the correct solution*)
  f[xs]
  Plot[{f[x], extrema[[3]]}, {x, xs, xm}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, 
  PlotRange ->All]
```

With this code I manage to get a solution which satisfies my boundary conditions:

[image]

However, if I increase the interval, i.e. if I take xm larger (e.g. xm=20), then I am not able to get any solution and Mathematica gives the following error:

```
At x$4813 == 18.5425691611345`, step size is effectively zero; \singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

The same problem happens if I change the value of the parameter $a$ in the potential. For instance, if I take $a=0.1$ I get the same error and cannot get a solution.

Could you please tell what I am doing wrong and how to improve my code in order to get a solution for larger intervals and also for different values of a?

I found slightly similar questions but none of them really helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: Suppose $y$ approaches the extremum near $y\approx0.9$ and at the same time $y'\approx0$. If a step puts $y$ greater than the extremum, $V'(y)$ will be positive, $y'$ will be positive but near zero, and $x$ will be somewhat large ($\gt10$).  Therefore $y'' = -3y'/x+V$ is likely to be positive, in which case the solution curve will be concave up and diverge to infinity (i.e., you get a singularity).  That pitfall makes the shooting method difficult to manage. Another consideration is that not every nonlinear BVP has a solution.

Answer (score 5):

We can play with initial value `ys` to get solution at `xm=20`. For this we should increase precision of roots as follows

```
a = 23/100;
V[y_] := (1/4) (y^2 - 1)^2 + a (y - 1)/(2);
ode = y''[x] + (3 y'[x])/x == V'[y[x]];
extrema = 
 Block[{y}, 
  Rationalize[
   y /. NSolve[D[V[y], y] == 0, y, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 50], 
   10^-49]]
```

Also we need to increase precision of solution

```
xs = 10^-8; xm = 20;
s = ParametricNDSolve[{ode, y'[xs] == 0, y[xm] == extrema[[3]]}, 
   y, {x, xs, xm}, {ys}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[xs] == ys, y'[xs] == 0}}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 30];
```

Finally we can plot desired solution playing with `ys` (this is really trick!)

```
f = y[extrema[[1]] + 2 10^-6 + 10^-7] /. 
  s;(*choosing the optimal value of ys to get the correct \
solution*)f[xs]
Plot[{f[x], extrema[[3]]}, {x, xs, xm}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Now we use the wavelets collocation method to get numerical solution for large and small intervals with `xm=L`. First, we map interval $(0,L)$ to $(0,1)$ using substitution $x\rightarrow L x$. Second, we use numerical solution at $L=21$ as initial guess to generate sequence of numerical solutions. Here we put `xm=1` since we map interval to $(0,1)$:

```
a = 23/100; L = 21;
V[y_] := (1/4) (y^2 - 1)^2 + a (y - 1)/(2);
ode = y''[x] + (3 y'[x])/x == L^2 V'[y[x]];
extrema = 
  Block[{y}, 
   Rationalize[
    y /. NSolve[D[V[y], y] == 0, y, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 120], 
    10^-119]];


xs = 10^-8; xm = 1;
s = ParametricNDSolve[{ode, y'[xs] == 0, y[xm] == extrema[[3]], 
    WhenEvent[y'[x] < 0, {xmax = x, "StopIntegration"}]}, 
   y, {x, xs, xm}, {ys}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[xs] == ys, y'[xs] == 0}}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 30];


pp = -(149643685212592894317733320513154810629526671825404636079551673\
152787/142087466431502699344020314203802217303945506305721123722555300\
000000); f = 
 y[pp] /. s;(*choosing the optimal value of ys to get the correct \
solution*)
Plot[{f[x], extrema[[3]]}, {x, xs, xm}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Numerical solution at $L=21$
[image: Figure 2]

With this code we calculate initial guess for Harr wavelets method:

```
 J = 5; M = 2^J; dx = 1/(2*M); h1[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, True}}]; 
  p1[x_, n_] := (1/n!)*x^n; 
h[x_, k_, m_] := Piecewise[{{1, Inequality[k/m, LessEqual, x, Less, (1 + 2*k)/(2*m)]}, 
    {-1, Inequality[(1 + 2*k)/(2*m), LessEqual, x, Less, (1 + k)/m]}}, 0]
p[x_, k_, m_, n_] := Piecewise[{{0, x < k/m}, {(-(k/m) + x)^n/n!, Inequality[k/m, LessEqual, x, 
      Less, (1 + 2*k)/(2*m)]}, {((-(k/m) + x)^n - 2*(-((1 + 2*k)/(2*m)) + x)^n)/n!, 
     (1 + 2*k)/(2*m) <= x <= (1 + k)/m}, 
    {((-(k/m) + x)^n + (-((1 + k)/m) + x)^n - 2*(-((1 + 2*k)/(2*m)) + x)^n)/n!, x > (1 + k)/m}}, 0]
xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, 2*M}]; xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, 2*M + 1}]; 
f2[x_] := Sum[af[i, j]*h[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + a0*h1[x]; 
  f1[x_] := Sum[af[i, j]*p[x, i, 2^j, 1], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + a0*p1[x, 1] + f10; 
  f0[x_] := Sum[af[i, j]*p[x, i, 2^j, 2], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + a0*p1[x, 2] + f10*x + 
    f00; 

bc = {f1[0] == 0, f0[1] == extrema[[3]]}; var = 
 Flatten[Table[af[i, j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]];
varM = Join[{a0, f10, f00}, var]; eq = Table[f0[x] == f[x], {x, xcol}];
eqM = Join[eq, bc];

sol0 = NSolve[eqM, varM];
```

Finally we compute sequence of numerical solutions for $21\le L\le 29$:

```
sol[0] = sol0[[1]]; L = 20; Do[L = L + 1; 
 eqn[x_] := f2[x] + (3 f1[x])/x - L^2 V'[f0[x]]; 
 eq1 = Table[eqn[x] == 0, {x, xcol}];
 eqM1 = Join[eq1, bc]; 
 sol[j] = FindRoot[eqM1, 
   Table[{varM[[i]], Last[sol[j - 1][[i]]]}, {i, Length[varM]}]];
 lst1 = Table[{x, Evaluate[f0[x] /. sol[j]]}, {x, xcol}];
 plot[j] = 
  Show[Plot[{f[x], extrema[[3]]}, {x, xs, xm}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"L = ", L}]], 
   ListPlot[lst1, PlotStyle -> Red]];, {j, 1, 9}]
```

Visualisation of numerical solutions (red points) together with initial guess (blue line)

```
Table[plot[j], {j, 9}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Final remarks: to get solution at $L>29$ we need to put in do loop `L=L+1/2`. For example,

```
sol[0] = sol[9]; L = 29; Do[L = L + 1/2; 
 eqn[x_] := f2[x] + (3 f1[x])/x - L^2 V'[f0[x]]; 
 eq1 = Table[eqn[x] == 0, {x, xcol}];
 eqM1 = Join[eq1, bc]; 
 sol[j] = FindRoot[eqM1, 
   Table[{varM[[i]], Last[sol[j - 1][[i]]]}, {i, Length[varM]}]];
 lst1 = Table[{x, Evaluate[f0[x] /. sol[j]]}, {x, xcol}];
 plot[j] = 
  Show[Plot[{f[x], extrema[[3]]}, {x, xs, xm}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"L = ", L // N}]], 
   ListPlot[lst1, PlotStyle -> Red]];, {j, 1, 10}]

Table[plot[j], {j, 10}]
```

[image: Figure 4]

For $L<21$ we use

```
sol[0] = sol0[[1]]; L = 21; Do[L = L - 1/4; 
 eqn[x_] := f2[x] + (3 f1[x])/x - L^2 V'[f0[x]]; 
 eq1 = Table[eqn[x] == 0, {x, xcol}];
 eqM1 = Join[eq1, bc]; 
 sol[j] = FindRoot[eqM1, 
   Table[{varM[[i]], Last[sol[j - 1][[i]]]}, {i, Length[varM]}]];
 lst1 = Table[{x, Evaluate[f0[x] /. sol[j]]}, {x, xcol}];
 plot[j] = 
  Show[Plot[{f[x], extrema[[3]]}, {x, xs, xm}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"L = ", L // N}]], 
   ListPlot[lst1, PlotStyle -> Red]];, {j, 1, 10}]
```

[image: Figure 5]

Comment: Hi Alex Trounev, many thanks for your answer, it helps me a lot. I was now trying to consider larger intervals (e.g xm=21), but I get again the same problem. Can you please tell me how I should proceed every time I want to increase xm? It is still not clear to me how to judge when to increase the precision of the root. Also, I would like to ask you whether you could suggest a more efficient way to find the correct initial condition ys, avoiding continuous ansatz.

Comment: For `xm=21` try `f = y[extrema[[1]] + 2 10^-6 + 2 10^-7 + 10^-8] /. s;` This play with `f` can be organize in some `Module[]` using `WhenEvent[]`. Alternatively we can use wavelets method to solve BVP. Is it 4D spherical Laplacian derived from Yang-Mills?

Comment: It would be very nice if you could tell me how to organize the play with `f `; I am not expert in numerical methods. The differential equation describes false vacuum decay for a real scalar field in 4 dimensions and is taken from Coleman's paper http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~steinh/ph564/Coleman.pdf
See for instance, Eq. 3.7 and 4.5. Many thanks again

Comment: @user92 Thank you for the paper linked.  Actually this problem also has obvious solution `y[x]=extrema[[3]]` even for `xm=Infinity`. The option "StartingInitialConditions" is a trick what you did to get physical solution. This working good for limited  `xm`, but it is not  working at all for large interval.

Comment: I see your point. Could you please suggest a method/code to solve the differential equation and get the physical solution for larger intervals?

Comment: @user92 See update to my answer with Haar wavelets method.

Comment: Pretty good -- thanks on posting your answer!

Comment: @AntonAntonov You are welcome!

Comment: Hi Alex, Many thanks for your detailed answer. Amazing! I will study it in detail and come back to you asap.

Comment: @user92 I am not tested code for varying `a`. Can you do it?

Comment: @AlexTrounev: yes, I will check it. Thanks.

Comment: @user92 You are welcome!

Comment: @Alex Trounev: My request may look irrelevant; if so, please just ignore it. What are the parameters (OS, RAM, etc) of your compure you generated the above results? and What is the MMA version you used?

Comment: @TugrulTemel Code been tested on vv 12.0.0, 12.1.1.0 for `$System` "Microsoft Windows (64-bit)", with  `$SystemMemory` of 17179869184.